# Adding share url into an iframe (facebook, twitter, linkedin)

Tags: facebook, iframe, twitter, linkedin-api

Is there any way to allow this to work:

```
Twitter:
<iframe src="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=this is a test"></iframe>

Facebook:
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com"></iframe>

Linkedin:
<iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://inspirationseek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Cherry-Blossom-Pretty-Flowers-Pictures.jpg&title=test&summary=test test"></iframe>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lj81z7xa/7/

> Refused to display
>   'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=this%20is%20a%20test' in a
>   frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'". (index):1
>
> Refused to display
>   'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. about:blank:1
>
> Refused to display
>   'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://inspirationseek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Cherry-Blossom-Pretty-Flowers-Pictures.jpg&title=test&summary=test%20test'
>   in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

Comment: No there is not. Don't display those links in iframes

Comment: Thanks for confirming

Comment: @WizKid - Want to put this as an answer?